How to test cookies set method was called x times in nextjs + jest
I'm currently working on a personal project with nextjs and trying to write some thest cases for the application using jest. I'm mocking nextjs/headers cookies().set method to be able to test that it was called x times inside a function but it always return that it was called 0 times.
Code to use as guide:
// handleLoginAction
export async function handleLoginAction(
  state: FormStateType,
  formData: FormData,
): Promise<FormStateType> {
  try {
    // Handle formData data and sign in user.

    const tokens: Tokens = {
      accessToken: response.access_token,
      refreshToken: response.refresh_token,
    };

    cookies().set(COOKIES_KEYS.ACCESS, tokens.accessToken);
    cookies().set(COOKIES_KEYS.REFRESH, tokens.refreshToken);
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle request error
  }

  redirect(ROUTES.HOME);
}

import { AuthService } from '@services';
import { FormStateType } from '@types';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { handleLoginAction } from './useLogin.hook';


jest.mock('next/navigation', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('next/navigation'),
  redirect: jest.fn(),
}));

jest.mock('next/headers', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('next/headers'),
  cookies: jest.fn(() => ({
    set: jest.fn(),
  })),
}));

describe('UseLogin hook tests', () => {
  describe('handleLoginAction tests', () => {
    it('Returns form state on success request', async () => {
      const formState: FormStateType = {};
      const formData: FormData = new FormData();
      const loginResponse: any = { access_token: 'access_token', refresh_token: 'refresh_token' };

      jest.spyOn(AuthService.prototype, 'login').mockResolvedValueOnce(loginResponse);

      const result: FormStateType = await handleLoginAction(formState, formData);

      expect(result).toBeUndefined();
      expect(redirect).toHaveBeenCalled();
      // Assert that cookies().set was called 2 times;
      expect(cookies().set).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
    });
  });
});

The mock is inded working for cookies().set() but the expect(cookies().set).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2) always fail.

For now i'm asserting that cookies was called x times with expect(cookies).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(x); it works as expected.
